# How to check if this is an element with class?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to see if an element IS an element with class. Not looking to check if it `hasClass` but if this is an element with class.

I tried this with no luck::

```
if ($(this).is("span .filter a")) { /* ... */ }
```

html:

```
<span class="filter">
  <a href="#">My el</a>
</span>
```

I need to check that I clicked on an `a` that is child of `span.filter`

Mybe something along

```
if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("filter")) {..do this..}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to check if `this` is a tag of a certain type that has a `class` attribute of any value? The goal of your question is not clear at all.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to check if the element that `this` references is of a specific tag type, and has a class of any value, you can try this:

```
if (this.tagName == "SPAN" && $(this).prop('class')) {
    console.log('this is a <span> that has a class');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ctkurx3b/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
if(jQuery(this).is('a') && jQuery(this).hasClass('className'))
```

Comment: not looking to check if this has a class as per my question but thanks for the effort

Comment: Then change it to if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('filter') && jQuery(this).parent().is('span'))